# How to change/create SIM PIN using AT commands when the SIM card has no PIN?

Tags: at-command, modem, pin-code

I'm using a SIM868 module and I was using my usual SIM card with no problem, but now I have bought a new SIM card and has no pin. I need to add a  PIN code in order to have more security.

I have checked that it has no PIN enabled using this command: `AT+CPIN?`.

and the answer was: `+CPIN: READY`.

I have searched how to change it in the SIMCOM's AT commands manual and I have found 2 options:

1. `AT+CPIN=<pin>[,<new pin>]`
2. `AT+CPWD=<fac>,<oldpwd>,<newpwd>`

I have tried both of them, but in the first one I can't insert the actual PIN, because there is no actual PIN. And in the second one I have tried different commands due, in the description of the AT command,  sais *"If an old password has not yet been set, `oldpwd` is not to enter"*. None of this ones has worked (guess that 1234 is the new PIN that I want to use)

```
1) AT+CLCK=“SC”,"1234"
2) AT+CLCK=“SC”,,"1234" 
3) AT+CLCK=“SC”,“”,"1234"
```

The answer to that 3 cases was the same: `ERROR`.

(If someone is going to suggest that I can change or try the SIM card with a mobile phone I can't do it because this new SIM card is a miniSIM card and all my phones use nanoSIM or microSIM).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR

In order to set the PIN code `1234` you need to provide the following command:

```
AT+CLCK="SC",1,"1234"
```

---

### Explanation

As you correctly wrote, `AT+CLCK` is the correct command to enable/disable any module's facility, included "SIM PIN request". But your syntax is wrong.

According to [ETSI specification](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/15.03.00_60/ts_127007v150300p.pdf), the correct syntax is

```
AT+CLCK=<fac>,<mode>[,<passwd>[,<class>]]
```

Where:

- `<fac>` (string) is the facility to be locked/unlocked (`"SC"` in case of *"SIM (PIN request)"*).
- `<mode>` (integer) is the operation to be done on the facility. **This parameter was missing in your attempts**.

  - **0** to unlock
  - **1** to lock
  - **2** to query lock status
- `<passwd>` is the password set with `+CPWD` (in your case it should be the PIN code but it is probably not required since it is not set).
- `<class>` is a sum of integers each representing a class of information. You don't need it for your task.

---

**Note:** in development phase, when "playing" with AT commands, I suggest enabling *verbose errors mode* providing either `AT+CMEE=1` or `AT+CMEE=2` according to what your device do support (check it by providing test command `AT+CMEE=?`).

Comment: https://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/gsmerrorcodes/ Check this out incase you ran into an error